# How to get code completion for cappuccino and objective-j?

Tags: ide, code-completion, cappuccino, objective-j

Is there an IDE/Text Editor that provides robust code completion/hinting for cappuccino and objective-j? Right now I use Text Mate and it provides syntax highlighting, but no code completion/hinting using new classes created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SubethaEdit or Coda you can use my bundle: https://github.com/Me1000/Objective-J-Cappuccino-Coda-SubethaEdit-bundle

(Coda has a built in bundle, but mine is a little more full featured in terms of method completion).

Sublime 2: https://github.com/aparajita/Cappuccino-Sublime I hear it works very well and is maintained by another of our core team members.

Comment: Do these provide code completion/hinting for newly created classes or only for existing framework classes?

Comment: My bundle will only work for existing classes. I'm not sure about the sublime bundle

Comment: What I was looking for is a package that auto-discovers new classes as they are made, it would speed up my development time quite a bunch. I have many classes and trying to remember the exact format of each method becomes impossible. I will try the SubEthaEdit bundle though.

Comment: Max Oxyn, it worked for me. All it really does is syntax highlighting, other than that it doesn't really provide code hinting besides some faux hinting using keywords. As a side note I have abandoned Cappuccino after spending many many hours writing an admin system. I am now back to plain Javascript for my project.